# Service Worker pre-loading sub-pages after pageloading

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I'm adding the HTML-Code for the ServiceWorker to the HTML-Page with following code:

```
    <script>
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("../service.js", {
            scope: "myScope"
        });
    </script>
```

Now I want to preload some pages, to get better performance on sideload. This is my code, which works fine:

```
    self.addEventListener("install", function (e) {
      e.waitUntil(
        caches.open("myCache").then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                "p1.html",
                "p2.html"]);
        })
      );
    });
```

But the sub-pages are loaded immediately if the service-script is available. On throtteling the network connection to gprs or edge this cause a lot problems!
So I want to have a solution to start caching those sites, after all other requests are over.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same Cache Storage API that you're using via `cache.addAll()` from within the `WorkerGlobalScope` is also exposed via `Window`. This means that you can modify the same caches from JavaScript that runs on your controlled pages, and you can wait for whatever `window`/`document`/whatever events are fired before you execute the `cache.addAll()`.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the cache population inside your service worker's `install` handler (to make sure that iff the service worker installs, the caches are always populated, for instance), you can simply delay calling  `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` until a certain event is fired on your page.